# Bash script to print file names and their sizes in the current directory

Tags: bash, shell, size

I just wrote a bash script to print the size and the name of all the files in a directory. It's quite simple:

```
du -h *
```

It prints first the size of the file and then the name.
But now I wonder how can I reverse the order of the output: print first the name and then the size of the file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
du -h * | awk -v FS='\t' '{ print $2, $1 }'
```

It works by taking the output from `du` and sending it to an inline `awk` script, which reads as follows: for every line given to `awk` in input, print the 2nd and then 1st column.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that and it only prints the first word of the name of the file... I want to get the full name

Comment: Your filenames have tabs and/or spaces?

Comment: Yes, is it a problem?

Comment: It'll just make the code a bit more complicated.  Try the command I just edited.  It should work as long as you don't have tabs in filenames (spaces are OK)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl based solution:

du -h *|perl -pe'/\s(.+)/&&{$_="$1\t$`\n"}'

It works properly for both spaces and tabs inside of file names.